# how to $.each loop through data retrive name,type,id below my code see this help us

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

how to $.each loop through data retrive name,type,id below my code see this help us:

```
if(this.checked) {
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    format: 'json',
    url: "dataview.php",
    data: "id=" + fid,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $.each(data, function(element, type) {
            alert(element + ": " + type);
            if(type == 'home') {
                $('#home').html('type:home<input type="checkbox">');
            }
        })
        if(type == 'office') {
            $('#office').html('type:office<input type="checkbox">');
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please try to provide the formatted code. I have edited your code and added parentheses wherever necessary.

Comment: In order to tell you how to iterate over `data`, we need to know the structure of the `data` object. Can you do `console.log(data)`, open the dev tools, and post a screenshot of the `data` object fully expanded? Or better yet, a sample of the JSON. Without that, we'd be guessing at best

Comment: is data like `{"name":"some name", "type": "some type", "id": "some id"}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what `data` looks like but I suspect it's something like:

`{"name":"some name", "type": "some type", "id": "some id"}`

If that is the case, then you simply need to call `data.name`, `data.type`, or `data.id`. Also, you can simplify your `if` logic by using the variable itself in the code, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  format: 'json',
  url: "dataview.php",
  data: "id=" + fid,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.type);
    $('#'+data.type).html('type:'+data.type+'<input type="checkbox">');
  }
});
```

**If the structure of `data` is different than I have guessed, you'll need to provide that structure for us to be of any further help**

Comment: @Barmar nice catch. I left it in from the OPs code and didn't look close enough at it

Comment: i am alert to see is an undefine

Comment: @janijaydip Im not sure what you are trying to say